# Setting Additional Data to highcharts tooltip with formatter doesn't work if points count exceed threshold

Tags: highcharts, tooltip

Trying to attach additional data to series tooltip using tooltip.formatter

There data for series looks like that:
`series: [{
        name: 'Series 1',
        data: [{ x:Math.rand(), label: "Test Label1"},
               { x:Math.rand(), label: "Test Label2"},
               { x:Math.rand(), label: "Test Label3"}
              ]
          }]`

And formatter:
`tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        formatter: function() {
            var result = '<b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) + '</b>';
            $.each(this.points, function(i, datum) {
                result += '<br />' + datum.point.label;
                            });
            return result;
        }
    }`

The problem is highchart expose additional fields in formatter function only if dots count in series doesn't trespass some threshold. Experimentally I found that it works for less than approximately 250 dots and depends on chart configuration.

Seems there is some internal throttling, but I cannot find any mentions of it in documentation.

There is example demonstrating an issue with 2 charts similar charts,but different series cardinality: 250 and 500 dots respectively - http://jsfiddle.net/k5exP/68/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is related with the fact that in the highstock you have enabled [datagrouping](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping), defaulty. It causes tht points are approximated and custom parameters are skipped.

Comment: Yes, indeed, disabling grouping with 
`dataGrouping: {
           enabled: true
}` solves problem